# API Testing using Protractor+AXIOS

Tags: javascript, protractor, axios

I am trying to hit an API and to get its response using AXIOS+Java Script+Protractor. I am getting below message in console, can someone please help me?

Code:

```
const axios = require('axios');
axios.get('jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
    .finally(function() {
        // always executed 
    });
```

Please find the below console log:

> Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.27.135.11:443
>           at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1161:14)
>         errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
>         code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
>         syscall: 'connect',
>         address: '104.27.135.11',
>         port: 443,
>         config:
>          { url: 'https://reqres.in/api/users/2',
>            method: 'get',
>            headers:
>             { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
>               'User-Agent': 'axios/0.19.0' },
>            transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
>            transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
>            timeout: 0,
>            adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
>            xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
>            xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
>            maxContentLength: -1,
>            validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
>            data: undefined },
>         request:
>          Writable {
>            _writableState:
>             WritableState {
>               objectMode: false,
>               highWaterMark: 16384,
>               finalCalled: false,
>               needDrain: false,
>               ending: false,
>               ended: false,
>               finished: false,
>               destroyed: false,
>               decodeStrings: true,
>               defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
>               length: 0,
>               writing: false,
>               corked: 0,
>               sync: true,
>               bufferProcessing: false,
>               onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
>               writecb: null,
>               writelen: 0,
>               bufferedRequest: null,
>               lastBufferedRequest: null,
>               pendingcb: 0,
>               prefinished: false,
>               errorEmitted: false,
>               emitClose: true,
>               bufferedRequestCount: 0,
>               corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
>            writable: true,
>            _events:
>             { response: [Function: handleResponse],
>               error: [Function: handleRequestError] },
>            _eventsCount: 2,
>            _maxListeners: undefined,
>            _options:
>             { protocol: 'https:',
>               maxRedirects: 21,
>               maxBodyLength: 10485760,
>               path: '/api/users/2',
>               method: 'GET',
>               headers: [Object],
>               agent: undefined,
>               auth: undefined,
>               hostname: 'reqres.in',
>               port: null,
>               nativeProtocols: [Object],
>               pathname: '/api/users/2' },
>            _redirectCount: 0,
>            _redirects: [],
>            _requestBodyLength: 0,
>            _requestBodyBuffers: [],
>            _onNativeResponse: [Function],
>            _currentRequest:
>             ClientRequest {
>               _events: [Object],
>               _eventsCount: 6,
>               _maxListeners: undefined,
>               output: [],
>               outputEncodings: [],
>               outputCallbacks: [],
>               outputSize: 0,
>               writable: true,
>               _last: true,
>               chunkedEncoding: false,
>               shouldKeepAlive: false,
>               useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
>               sendDate: false,
>               _removedConnection: false,
>               _removedContLen: false,
>               _removedTE: false,
>               _contentLength: 0,
>               _hasBody: true,
>               _trailer: '',
>               finished: true,
>               _headerSent: true,
>               socket: [TLSSocket],
>               connection: [TLSSocket],
>               _header:
>                'GET /api/users/2 HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nUser-Agent: axios/0.19.0\r\nHost:
>   reqres.in\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
>               _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
>               agent: [Agent],
>               socketPath: undefined,
>               timeout: undefined,
>               method: 'GET',
>               path: '/api/users/2',
>               _ended: false,
>               res: null,
>               aborted: undefined,
>               timeoutCb: null,
>               upgradeOrConnect: false,
>               parser: null,
>               maxHeadersCount: null,
>               _redirectable: [Circular],
>               [Symbol(isCorked)]: false,
>               [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
>            _currentUrl: 'https://reqres.in/api/users/2' },
>         response: undefined,
>         isAxiosError: true,
>         toJSON: [Function] }

Comment: please add some code and more information so that the community can help you out. For instance, What code you ran that gave this error ?

Comment: Please find the below code which i have used

Comment: const axios = require('axios');
 

axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(function (response) {
    
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    
    console.log(error);
  })
  .finally(function () {
    // always executed
  });

Comment: @DivyaReddy Is your response logged ? for the first `then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this ETIMEDOUT error might be some proxy in front of this endpoint. If that is the reason, then you should modify your request config by passing the proxy host and port along with the endpoint URL.

Comment: Modified the config request with below proxy  exports.config = {
    
    // seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    directconnect : "true",
  
    
    capabilities: {
      browserName: 'firefox',
      "proxy": {
        "host": "http:myorganizationproxy.com",
        "port": 80
      }
    },
    specs: ['test.js'],
  };

Comment: Getting below message in console [05:03:12] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://51.19.137.62:54871/wd/hub
[05:03:15] E/launcher - Unable to create session from {

Comment: Is this the axios config where you set the proxy? I think it's not. You should configure your axios instance. I now see that I wasn't very clear about that.